# Magento 2: Admin listing take long loading time on WAMP

Tags: magento2, admin, wamp

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.0. It's installed on WAMP on Windows 10 64- Bit.

[image]
However I have noticed, if there are only 3-4 records, still it takes long loading time (Approximately 15-20 seconds).

Did any one face this issue?

How to increase page loading time?

Answer (score 1):

- Set Magento to Developer mode (get details from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html)).
- Remove comment from magento 2 htaccess file from line (# SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer).
  make memory_limit = 2024mb for local
- Enable Cache.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

**Suggestion:** If above solution does not work, then please check Magento's performance in Ubuntu or any other linux environment.

Windows is not officially supported, only Linux distributions are supported for production mode. See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

**Update:** Please follow below instructions, if above solution didn't work:

- set Magento to production mode in the magento root folder:
  **`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`**
- set static content files: **`php magento setup:static-content:deploy`**
- set di compile: **`php magento setup:di:compile`**
- Flush Magento cache.
- Remove these folders, if you make any changes in code: **/var/view_preprocessed**, contents under **/pub/static** folder (except **`.htaccess`** file)

Comment: I followed your steps. Still same issue. I'm using developer mode on WAMP. May be it works on Linux. For Windows any solution?

Comment: I'm currently doing development. So i set it on Developer Mode. Instead of Developer if i put it on Production then what it will effect to my developer mode?